# How to recover files in Ubuntu partition through Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, dell, data-recovery

Long story short, installing Ubuntu on an XPS 13 (2015) with Windows on it, I screwed up and lost Windows. Fast forward to today, I have Windows back, but I'd like to get some files back from my Ubuntu partition.

I'm not comfortable with repairing Grub (unless that's *really* the surest way). I really don't want to go through having Windows break again, and so I'm looking for a way to get the files off my Ubuntu partition, delete it, and boot back to Windows. Minimum fuss. I'll start over with dual booting another day.

I know where the files are. What's the best way for me to get to them, best meaning least likely to screw up Windows 10 on an XPS 13?

Comment: You can use a (Ubuntu) live session for that. Otherwise you would have to use third party tools for Windows and both those tools and Windows is off-topic here.

Comment: "How to recover files in Ubuntu partition through Windows?" makes it a window related question and thus offtopic. Besides that: not possible (through windows).

Comment: @Rinzwind it is possible, but of course still OT as you said. I'm voting to close now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Windows but I already had to recover files from Ubuntu. If you put the cd/usb install of Ubuntu and you "Try Ubuntu", normally you should can accede your Ubuntu partition. So you just have to put an external HDD or another usb and you should can recover these files. You normally should can accede your Windows partition from there so if you just want to move these files to your Windows partition, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: To add to @Aegefel's advice: after you boot to the DVD or thumb drive and "Try Ubuntu", you'll need to mount the Linux and NTFS partitions to move files around, which you should be able to do in Nautilus (the graphical file manager).  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can install an ExtFS driver for Windows, which would make Ubuntu partitions accessible, and copy files easily.

Two drivers are available:

- [commercial with free trial from Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows-pro/index.html?utm_source=top-banner&utm_medium=ext-win-free-page&utm_campaign=extfs-win-free)
- [free one](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?p=219)

PS: That's one of the ways, but I'd refrain from claiming it best or bestest.